# Convert Django framework to Django rest framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

To make the curl post request work, I am converting my existing Django project to Django REST framework.

I have installed djangorestframework==3.12.4.

My **settings.py**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ....
    'rest_framework',
]

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    # Use Django's standard `django.contrib.auth` permissions,
    # or allow read-only access for unauthenticated users.
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.permissions.DjangoModelPermissionsOrAnonReadOnly'
    ]
}
```

My **views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from . import forms
from . import student_details_module
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect


def student_details(request):
    submitted = False
    print (request)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = forms.studentDetailsForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            cd = form.cleaned_data
            return_message,return_code = student_details_module.show_data(cd['name'])
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/student_details?submitted=True')
    else:
        form = forms.studentDetailsForm()
        if 'submitted' in request.GET:
            submitted = True

    return render(request,
        'student_details.html',
        {'form': form, 'submitted': submitted}
        )
```

How do I convert my view so it works well with djangorestframework. Please suggest.

Comment: Maybe reading the DRF documentation would help? I'd suggest `Views`, `Generic Views` and `Viewsets` as a start

Comment: Thanks, I am gone through the DRF documentation but I didnt get how do I convert my (below code ) as I am submitting the input to another python module and getting results back from it. 
 ```  return_message,return_code = student_details_module.show_data(cd['name'])
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/student_details?submitted=True')```